# Multiple Monitors not Detected, Radeon RX580 on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, radeon, amdgpu, 21.10

I'm running a Radeon RX580 on Ubuntu 21.10. I've been using Ubuntu on this machine since late 2018 with no real graphics issues. Yesterday morning (Nov. 10 2021) the system had updates and asked me to reboot. When I did, the single HMDI monitor is detected, but the two display port monitors are not. xrandr does not show the other drivers, and passing the various AMD flags into the grub config does not change anything. The system dual-boots with Windows 11 and all three monitors work fine there, so the cables, ports, etc are not the question. I can boot off a live USB and get all three in Ubuntu as well. If I have to I can reinstall the OS but I'd rather get it working.